# TinyXML2 - Reading data from elements

Tags: android, c++, xml, parsing, tinyxml2

I have this XML file which I want to be able to read certain text out of. I'm parsing it using TinyXML2. This is an Android XML file, and it's written different to regular XML files.

What I want to do is read from the android:pathData tag within the path element in this file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector android:height="64.0dip" android:width="64.0dip" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M12.05,7.7c-1.1,0,-2,0.94,-2,2.05v0.5h4v-0.5C14.05,8.65,13.15,7.7,12.05,7.7z" />
    <path android:fillColor="@*common:color/qs_toggles_color" android:pathData="M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z" />
    <path android:fillColor="@*common:color/qs_toggles_color" android:pathData="M16.5,2.5c3.3,1.5 5.6,4.7 6.0,8.5L24.0,11.0C23.4,4.8 18.3,0.0 12.0,0.0c-0.2,0.0 -0.4,0.0 -0.7,0.0l3.8,3.8L16.5,2.5zM7.5,21.5c-3.3,-1.5 -5.6,-4.7 -6.0,-8.5L0.1,13.0C0.6,19.2 5.7,24.0 12.0,24.0c0.2,0.0 0.4,0.0 0.7,0.0l-3.8,-3.8L7.5,21.5z" />
</vector>
```

The program would output all of the text within the "android:pathData" tag. For example:

```
M12.05,7.7c-1.1,0,-2,0.94,-2,2.05v0.5h4v-0.5C14.05,8.65,13.15,7.7,12.05,7.7z
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should post your current code.

Comment: @AlbertoM I don't have any code, ad I said it's an Android XML file which is very different to regular xml files so I have no idea how to read elements from it.